# useReducer hook state is getting reinitialized when I am navigating in the application

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

Every time when I navigate from policy page to test page my reducer state is changing ie: `Count: 0`.

When I console log the state inside the `ProtectedRoutes` component I can see that the state is getting re-initialized when I am changing the routes. I'm using `NavLink` from `react-router-dom` to change the routes.

index page

```
import React from 'react'
import { Reducer, initialState } from "./Reducer";

export default function Test() {
    const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(Reducer, initialState);

    console.log(state, "state -----")

    React.useEffect(() => {
        console.log(state)
        dispatch({ type: "FETCH_SUCCESS", payload: '' });

    }, [])

    return (
        <div>index</div>
    )
}
```

Reducer code

```
export const initialState = {
    count: 0,
}

export const Reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'FETCH_SUCCESS':
            return {
                ...state,
                count: 1,
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Router

```
import React from 'react'
import { Suspense } from 'react';
import { useRoutes } from 'react-router-dom'
import { ProtectedRoutes } from './ProtectedRoutes';
import Policy from '../Components/Policy';
import Test from '../Components/Test'

const Routes = () => {
  let element = useRoutes([
    {
      element: <ProtectedRoutes />,
      children: [
        { path: '/policy', element: <Policy /> },
        { path: '/test', element: <Test /> }
      ],
    },
    
  ]);
  return element;
}

const Router = () => {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
      <Routes />
    </Suspense>
  )
}

export default Router
```

Protected Routes

```
import React from 'react'
import { Navigate, useLocation, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useAuth } from '../Context/authContext'
import Header from './../Components/Header'
import { Reducer, initialState } from "./../Components/Test/Reducer";

export const ProtectedRoutes = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(Reducer, initialState);

  console.log(state, "ProtectedRoutes ")

  const auth = useAuth();
  const location = useLocation()
  if (auth.user && auth.user.role !== 'admin') {
    return <Navigate to='/' state={{ path: location.pathname }} />
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: The `Test` component maintains its own state, so it makes sense that when you navigate to `"/test"` and `Test` mounts that it starts with the initial state. In other words, when you navigate *from* `"/test"` then `Test` is unmounted and the state is garbage collected. Are you expecting to persist the state somewhere more long term than the life of the `Test` component?

Comment: Hi @DrewReese thank you for your feedback,  Yes i need the state persist if i navigate and come back to the /test route. im not that much familiar with useReducer hook, i worked with redux store and i was able to get the state in different component . With useReducer i feel like it is very similar to usestate and when im navigating the state is getting reset. how can i maintain the state?

Answer (score 1):

> I worked with redux store and I was able to get the state in different
> component. With `useReducer` I feel like it is very similar to
> `useState` and when I'm navigating the state is getting reset.

While both Redux and the `useReducer` hook use dispatched actions and reducer functions to effect state changes, that is about the extent of any similarities. Yes, the `useReducer` hook is a lot more like the `useState` hook, and different `useReducer` and `useState` hooks don't share any state; each one instantiates and maintains its own state. `ProtectedRoutes` and `Test` each have their own `useReducer` hook and state that maintain. When `Test` mounts, it instantiates the state, and when the UI navigates away from `"/test"` and `Test` unmounts, the state is thrown away, e.g. garbage collected.

> How can I maintain the state?

There should be a single common source of truth, typically located at or near the app root, or lower in the ReactTree at the highest common ancestor component. See the old [Lifting State Up](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) and current [Sharing State between Components](https://react.dev/learn/sharing-state-between-components) documentation.

In other words, promote the state to a common ancestor and provide it down the ReactTree via props or a React context.

In this case, since the `ProtectedRoutes` is the root layout route ***and*** is rendering an `Outlet` it is a perfect candidate to provide the state and `dispatch` function out on its provided `Outlet` context provider.

Example:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Navigate, useLocation, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useAuth } from '../Context/authContext'
import Header from './../Components/Header'
import { Reducer, initialState } from "./../Components/Test/Reducer";

export const ProtectedRoutes = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(Reducer, initialState);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("ProtectedRoutes", state);
  }, [state]);

  const auth = useAuth();
  const location = useLocation();

  if (auth.user?.role !== 'admin') {
    return <Navigate to='/' state={{ path: location.pathname }} replace />;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <Outlet context={{ state, dispatch }} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Downstream consumers will use the [useOutletContext](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-outlet-context) hook to access this provided context value.

```
import React from 'react'
import { useOutletContext } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Test() {
  const { state, dispatch } = useOutletContext();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(state);
    dispatch({ type: "FETCH_SUCCESS" });
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log({ state });
  }, [state]);

  return (
    <div>index</div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit usereducer-hook-state-is-getting-reinitialized-when-i-am-navigating-in-the-appli]

If you had a need to place this state higher to make it accessible to more than just the routed components then you could use a regular old React Context provider component and the `useContext` hook to do the same thing.

Comment: If i have multiple reducers then this method i cant use it right?

Comment: @RobinThomas This method would still work, though you'd need to modify it a bit. You could give each `useReducer` hook's state and dispatch function a unique name, e.g. `stateA`, `dispatchA`, `stateB`, `dispatchB`, etc, and provide these all on a single `Outlet` or React Context, but this could get a little unwieldy quickly. If you have *many* `useReducer` hooks then I'd suggest either individual context providers, a single `useReducer` for a single *large* state object, or bump to using a tool more suitable for managing larger global state, e.g. Redux.